# Выводит не всё заданное в приложение

Tags: c++, qt

Приложение на qt начинает работу при нажатии кнопки. Соответственно вся следующая работа происходит в on_pushbutton_clicked(). Начинает работать всё с добавления текста в label, но тут возникает проблема: выполняется только последнее добавление текста (я проверил). Как сделать так чтобы выводилось всё?

```
`void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    fstream test;
    string path = "test.txt";
    string path1 = "ans.txt";
    int quest_n = 1;
    int gresult=0;
    test.open(path, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    if (!test.is_open())
    {
         ui->label->setText("Ошибка");
    }
    else
    {
           ui->label->setText("Название тест");
           Sleep(5000);
           string strC;
           ui->label->setText("вписать");
    }
}
```

Извините за неправильные термины.

Comment: что и куда добавляется?

Comment: имеется ввиду setText().

Comment: А что за Sleep ? Откуда эта функция ? Попробуйте вместо неё [QThread::mslepp](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#msleep)

Comment: Ну а сама по себе попытка усыпить GUI поток - так себе. У вас на 5 секунд интерфейс зависнет же.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы отобразился текст "Название тест", то надо обновить метку перед паузой:

```
//...
ui->label->setText("Название тест");
ui->label->repaint(); // Обновить метку немедля!
Sleep(5000);
//...
```

Comment: `repaint` не нужен, setText достаточно. Я бы насчет `Sleep(5000);` задумался -- скорее всего там обычный sleep, что на текущий поток влияет, а это будет главный поток из-за чего все приложение на 5 секунд зависнет

Comment: @gil9red не достаточно, поскольку при изменении значения текста обновление метки происходит при помощи вызова update - который просто добавляет событие обновления в главную очередь событий и, соответственно, обновление произойдет только после завершения работы функции обработки клика. Чтобы немедленно обновить значение метки надо вызвать метод repaint, иначе мы увидим только "вписать".

Comment: Почему вы решили что нужно завершения функции? Создайте в той же on_pushButton_clicked вместо `sleep` -- `QEventLoop` и запустите его. Сразу же после клика увидите что название поменяется и без `repaint`, и при этом функция не завершится из-за QEventLoop'а

Comment: @gil9red Но зачем же мне созадвать еще один луп, если я просто могу вызвать repaint? Тем более что это интуитивно понятнее.

Comment: Затем что вы утверждаете `обновление произойдет только после завершения работы функции обработки клика`, а я написал что это не так -- QEventLoop не даст завершиться функции при этом обработка событий не будет заморожена в отличии от вызова Sleep (реально, это очень плохая идея и обходить ее через костыли выглядит странно). Я не писал что repaint неправильный или что-то в этом роде -- тот ведь поможет т.к. напрямую дернет событие перерисовки QLabel'а

Comment: @gil9red во-первых я ответил только на вопрос `Начинает работать всё с добавления текста в label, но тут возникает проблема: выполняется только последнее добавление текста (я проверил). Как сделать так чтобы выводилось всё?` то есть на счет Sleep вообще речи не идет. Понятно, что он тормозит свой гуи (да и приложение в целом) на 5 сек, но это дело хозяйское, вопрос не об этом. Во-вторых, в какой момент произойдет отрисовка текста метки при его изменении?

Comment: `>> Во-вторых, в какой момент произойдет отрисовка текста метки при его изменении? ` как виджет вызовет у себя paintEvent, а это происходит либо напрямую (repaint) либо по событию из цикла обработки событий. Событие перерисовки добавится при `update`, которое будет вызвано при `setText`. Предлагаю закончить на этом, т.к. это во флуд превращается :)